# How to fix the circular dependency?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm developing an application and I'm having issue with circular dependency in my Swagger class.
Even setting the `circular-references` as true, I still getting error.

This the code:

```
    private static final String SWAGGER_CONFIG = "/v3/api-docs/swagger-config";
    private static final String SWAGGER_URL = "/v3/api-docs";
    private static final List<String> CONTROLLER_PACKAGES =
            List.of("com.example.desafiobackvotos.controller");

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfig(SpringDocConfigProperties config){
        config.setPackagesToScan(CONTROLLER_PACKAGES);
        return config;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public SwaggerUiConfigProperties swaggerUiConfig(SwaggerUiConfigProperties config){
        config.setConfigUrl(SWAGGER_CONFIG);
        config.setUrl(SWAGGER_URL);
        return config;
    }
```

And this is the error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌──->──┐
|  springDocConfig defined in class path resource [com/example/desafiobackvotos/config/SpringFoxConfig.class]
└──<-──┘


Action:

Despite circular references being allowed, the dependency cycle between beans could not be broken. Update your application to remove the dependency cycle.


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I'm using `spring-boot` 3.0.6 and this dependency in pom:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.15</version>
        </dependency>
``
```

Comment: what is your spring-boot version and which dependency are you using for swagger? please update your question with this information.

Comment: @Abhishek I'm using spring-boot 3.0.6 and I updated the question, adding the dependency.

Comment: I'll suggest to use only one dependency which is 'springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui' and no additional configuration is needed so you can remove code from SpringFoxConfig class.  https://springdoc.org/v2/#spring-webmvc-support

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug in springdoc. The dependency cycle occurs if you have configured SwaggerUi programmatically as shown in the [documentation](https://springdoc.org/v2/#how-can-i-set-swagger-properties-programmatically), or if you have configured SpringDoc programmatically and moved the SwaggerUi config to the `application.properties`. I've recently (yesterday) [raised an issue](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/2259) on this topic.

Current **workaround** is to define all configurations in the `application.properties`.

```
springdoc.packages-to-scan=com.example.desafiobackvotos.controller
springdoc.swagger-ui.config-url=/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/v3/api-docs
```

Be aware that some configurations you want to set are the [defaults](https://springdoc.org/v2/#swagger-ui-properties) and you should use the `springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui` dependency ([Springdoc Getting Started](https://springdoc.org/v2/#getting-started)) as [@Abhishek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7012221/abhishek) has already pointed out.